# psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "source_id_id" of relation "service_approval_domains" does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models, psycopg2

I have created model in django for my database. After trying to add data to table I got this error:

`

```
lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "source_id_id" of relation "service_approval_domains" does not exist
LINE 1: ...domains" ("domain", "created_at", "retrieved_at", "source_id...
                                                             ^
```

I am not really sure where is the problem since I have checked everything and did not find any declaration of `source_id_id` column.

Here is my model:

```py
class ServiceApprovalDomains(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    domain = models.TextField(unique=True ,null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    retrieved_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    source_id = models.ForeignKey(
        ServiceApprovalDomainSources, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '"privacy"."service_approval_domains"'
```

And I used manual migration so here is my SQL file:

```
CREATE TABLE "privacy"."service_approval_domains"(
    "id" BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "domain" TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    "created_at" timestamp with time zone not null default current_timestamp,
    "retrieved_at" timestamp with time zone default current_timestamp,
    "source_id" bigserial not null references service_approval_domain_sources("id") on delete cascade
);
```

And this is the function I am using to add data to database:

```py
def add_domains(data: list[AddServiceApprovalDomains]):
    for domain in data:
        source = ServiceApprovalDomainSources.objects.get_or_create(name=domain.source.name)
        try:
            ServiceApprovalDomains.objects.create(domain=domain.domain, source_id=source[0])
        except IntegrityError:
            pass
    return True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make a `ForeignKey` named *`foo`*, django uses `foo_id` as name of the column to store the primary key it refers to.

So you can rename the `ForeignKey` to `source`:

```
class ServiceApprovalDomains(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    domain = models.TextField(unique=True, null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    retrieved_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    source = models.ForeignKey(
        ServiceApprovalDomainSources, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '"privacy"."service_approval_domains"'
```